# loop over subdirectories and apply command

Tags: linux, loops, unix, grep

I have many sub directories, each one of them contains .txt files and a .fastq file. I want to do something on each txt file and their corresponding file in each sub directory

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$1

subdirectories=$(find $dir -type d) # find only subdirectories in dir

for subdir in $subdirectories;do
    cd $subdir
    p_files=$(find . -name '*v1.txt') # find all the txt files in that subdirectory
    
    fq_file=$(find . -name '*v1.fastq') # find all the fastq files in that subdirectory
    
    for f in $p_files;do
        for q in $fq_file;
        do
            grep -A3 -f "$f" "$q" > "${f%.txt}_ex.fastq"
        done
    done
done
```

I want to grep on each single txt file in each directory with its fastq counterpart and output a new file.

Comment: You're not processing corresponding `.txt` and `.fastq` files. You're creating a cartesian product between them when you use nested loops.

Comment: Just get a list of all the txt files. Then get its corresponding fastq by replacing `.txt` with `.fastq` in the filename.

Comment: Note that your way of looping over directories and files will not work if any of them have whitespace in the names.

Comment: Your details are unclear. Are the txt and fastq files 1:1? Or could there be multiple (or zero) text files?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have these files (`tree` is an installed program...):

```
$ tree .
.
├── dir_A
│   ├── file.fastq
│   └── file.txt
├── dir_B
│   ├── file.fastq
│   └── file.txt
├── dir_C
│   ├── file.fastq
│   └── file.txt
└── dir_D
    ├── file.fastq
    └── file.txt
```

Rather than using `find` a bunch of times you can do something like this with a [recursive glob](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287093/bash-recursive-command-to-include-files-of-current-directory-files-as-wel):

```
for fq in **/*.fastq; do
    ft="${fq%.fastq}.txt"
    echo "$fq => $ft"
done
```

In this micro example, prints:

```
dir_A/file.fastq => dir_A/file.txt
dir_B/file.fastq => dir_B/file.txt
dir_C/file.fastq => dir_C/file.txt
dir_D/file.fastq => dir_D/file.txt
```

As you go through the loop now, `$fq` and `$ft` are set to the path name (relative to where the loop started) and you should be able to do what you want.

For Bash, make sure that `shopt globstar` is set to on with `shopt -s globstar`.